# Unable to Start Debugging. visual studio 2012 prompt after one time debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, 64-bit, iis-express

I am getting this error "`Unable to Start Debugging`" in visual studio 2012.

I have also update the remote debugging sp2.

also uninstalled and reinstalled vs2012 and added sp. still facing the same issue.

My operating system is windows-8 64 bit.

Also tried to run in Administrator user still the same.

[image]

Unable to Start Debugging. visual studio 2012

Comment: No, I installed visual studio 2013 RTM.

Answer (score 35):

Save your work, close Visual Studio then reopen your project

Comment: strange, but this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in my Visual Studio 2013. The solution I found is easy.

Just right-click the project you want to debug, and choose "Set as StartUp Project".

Hope I helped someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and fixed it by updating my credentials in the "Identity" setting, under IIS/Application Pools.

My password had recently changed, but the "Identity" was still set to my old credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem this morning. Installing Visual Studio 2013 wasn't an option for me (And I very much doubt it would be for lots of people). Rebooting has usually solved the problem before, (and a bit less drastic),

Manually attaching the process (TOOLS -> Attach to process (ctrl + ALT +p)) to  w3wp.exe for IIS, or IIsExpress.exe also worked, which leads me to suspect that VS is having trouble figuring out which process it should attach to automatically.

Comment: Out of all the SO posts and other forums on this issue, this is the only thing that worked.  What is weird, is that for other projects and solutions, when trying to debug, Visual Studio automatically attaches to the w3wp.exe process.  However, on the one solution/project that we're having issues with, and also only on the one workstation, we are having to manually attach to the w3wp.exe process every time we are debugging.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an actual question to answer, but maybe this will help somebody. I have the same problem with VS2012 on Windows 8.1, even with Update 4 of Visual Studio and Remote Tools. I can get around it by manually closing IIS Express with the task bar icon between debugs. It is still really annoying, but at least it works, at least most of the time. One time it didn't seem to help and I had to reboot, but after that it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click web application properties -> Properties Windows, Use dynamic ports to "False" and give some port number.  This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case this was a web solution, I had this problem when in a slightly different scenario, a second more elaborate error message appeared, with the the following reading:

"Unable to start 'solution name'. Either a Web Browser is not installed on this computer or a default browser has not been configured in Microsoft Visual Studio."

And yes, my IE was temporarilly uninstalled, due to other issues. After reinstalling IE, this all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Juste got the same today with VS2010. "Unable to start debugging...a dynamic DLL cannot be found". Also while opening this old project an non-build error in the outpout window: "Unable to find assembly <...>.dll in App_Data\Temp".

Solution: target framework was still at version 3, changed to 4 and then it works.