# Visual Studio 2012 "Unable to start debugging"

Tags: c#, web-services, debugging, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I am trying to host web services with IIS Express on my local machine. I can start debugging one time. Every time after that I get a dialog box with "Unable to Start Debugging" whenever I try to run the project. If I shut down VS 2012 then open back up it works one more time. I see the issue in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045361/unable-to-start-debugging-visual-studio-2012-prompt-after-one-time-debug.). 
I believe it has something to do with my password changing a few days ago. However, I can't find where my credentials are stored and I have no idea how to change this configuration. Please help!

UPDATE:

Turns out the same thing happens if I try to run a local console app. This means (I think) it is a VS setting somewhere. I was having to shut down VS and restart it every time. However, I did find that if I shut down these tasks and then debug it works:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Two things to check: 1, on your project properties tab make sure you have it assigned to a specific port number so it always uses the same one. It's possible that even though you stop debugging that the process is still running on the previous port. 2, if you feel as though it may be an authentication issue then make sure when you start up visual studio that you "run as administrator".

Comment: I've always had a specific port specified. It's just easier that way when testing web service calls. I tried running as administrator and unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: The thread you referred to is unresolved. To resolve your own issue, make sure you first understand the settings in VS and IIS Express, https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/11/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration/ then you might find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It appears from your screenshot that IIS Express is not shutting down when you stop debugging. This is actually a setting in Visual Studio called “Enable Edit and Continue”. When enabled, IISExpress will close when Debugging ends and if disabled IISExpress will remain open.

This setting is normally set on by default in Visual Studio 2013, but actually defaulted to *off* in versions prior, including 2012, which you state you're using. You probably want it **ON.**

To adjust globally:

1. Open Options dialog box by clicking Tools -> Options
2. Click Debugging -> Edit and Continue
3. Toggle "Enable Edit and Continue"

You can also turn adjust on a per project basis.

1. Open properties for web project
2. Click Web tab
3. Toggle Enable Edit and Continue" under Debugger at the bottom of this page

Further reading on MSDN here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/07/11/enable-edit-and-continue-debugging-option-is-now-on-by-default-for-new-web-applications-in-vs2013-preview/

Comment: This option is enabled. For giggles I tried turning it off and that didn't work either. It's looking like a fresh install is my only option at this point.

Comment: Is it enabled both globally, and within each project? Make sure its set to ON in all places.

Comment: That option isn't there for the Web Sites I have in my solution. Maybe because they were added as a "Web Site" and not "Web Application" (I don't even see an option to add a new project for that anymore). I do see the the Debuggers list under Start Options for each project, but the Enable and Continue option isn't present as it is in the blog. Regardless, this is happening for every project including test console applications.

Answer (score 0):

**First Check the Identity settings**

Update your credentials in the "Identity" setting, under IIS/Application Pools.

if your password had recently changed, the "Identity" might still set to your old credentials.

OR

**Reset Visual Studio Settings**

reset visual studio settings and restart it again.

1. On the Tools menu, click Import and Export Settings.
2. On the Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard page, click Reset    all settings and then click Next.
3. If you want to save your current settings combination, click Yes, save my current settings, specify a file name, and then click Next.

—or—

If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings, and then click Next. This option does not delete default settings, which will still be available the next time you use the wizard.

4. In Which collection of settings do you want to reset to, select a settings collection from the list.
5. Click Finish.

OR Check [Truely Reset VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012)